# c++ file naming(numbering) with file I/O

Tags: c++, file, io

I want to break a single large file into multiple smaller files based on a desired final file size.

example:

split size = `1024`
input file: `"Input.txt"`, `5027 byte`
output: `"Output1.txt", "Output2.txt", "Output3.txt" ...`

but I don't know how can I numbering to file name like

```
"Output<1>.txt" "Output<2>.txt" "Output<3>.txt" ..
```

I heard if I use `sprintf`, but I can't make use of that.

Comment: I missed out "hello" :-P

Comment: Use [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) maybe?

Comment: why you cant use sprintf?

Comment: @LeeSuhyun I have reworded your question to hopefully make it more clear, if you feel i incorrectly interpreted your question feel free to rollback or re-edit the question

Comment: @LeeSuhyun Being able to look at your surrounding code would help with providing applicable answers. Is your code modular enough that you could  paste that in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy to do, but first lets assume some things:

- `int size` is the size of "Input.txt"
- "Input.txt" has been successfully opened in the `ifstream input_txt`
- `int split_size` is the desired split size

You'll just want to setup a `while`-loop that creates and writes to your `ofstream`s, using a counter to create your filename:

```
auto i = min(split_size, size);
const char buffer[split_size];

while(i < size) {
    ofstream output_txt("output" + to_string(i / split_size) + ".txt");

    input_txt.read(buffer, split_size);
    output_txt.write(buffer, split_size);
    i += min(split_size, size - i);
}

if(i > 0) {
    ofstream ouput_txt("output" + tostring(1 + size / split_size) + ".txt");

    input_txt.read(buffer, size % split_size);
    output_txt.write(buffer, size % split_size);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const size_t chunk_size = 1024;
for (int i = 0; canReadMore();++i){
   ofstream out("Output"+std::to_string(i)+".txt"); // the string concatenation can be optimized by using reserve + append.
   char buffer[chunk_size];     
   size_t readBytes = readChunkSize(buffer, chunk_size); // This will be your read N bytes function
   out.write(buffer, readBytes);

}
```

Read about [to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) and [ofstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream)

Comment: I'm not goot at English, so my writing is bad but your answer is good :) thanks

Comment: @bashrc Just wondering, how would this get out of the loop? Error when trying to read from an empty stream?

Comment: @JonathanMee added a pseudo condition

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use stringstream. Here's an example of how to create five numbered file names, added to a vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    std::vector<std::string> vec;

    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        ss << "Output<" << i << ">.txt";
        vec.push_back(ss.str());
        ss.str(std::string());
        ss.clear();
    }
    return 0;
}
```